# Where can I file a bug report for Atlassian confluence

Tags: confluence, bug-reporting

I tried multiple times to find the place where I can file bug reports for [confluence](https://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence). Using google I always end on pages describing/trying to sell confluence or jira. And trying to navigate on the Atlassian pages is not really helping.

So does anybody know where I can file bug reports?

**Update:** 
I found this [page](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Troubleshooting+Problems+and+Requesting+Technical+Support) but following the link and navigation endlessly through their Jira I still could not find the place where I can file a bug for confluence... The navigation is just not very intuitive (maybe it was if I was a kangaroo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently confluence team is using this jira project

https://jira.atlassian.com/secure/RapidBoard.jspa?rapidView=1159&projectKey=CONF

Answer (score 0):

And this one is the restricted [Kanban board](https://jira.atlassian.com/secure/RapidBoard.jspa?rapidView=137&projectKey=CONF) which is used by the Atlassian developers.